# How do I get a list of domain user accounts with win32 api?

Tags: c++, winapi, active-directory

How do I get a list of domain user accounts with win32 api?

In particular, I can't get this list when the computer is not the domain controller.  Instead it is a member of the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the LDAP API.  This will let you query the LDAP server which will have a list of the user accounts.

Answer (score 2):

Just use netw apis.